# Magento attributes in view.phtml

Tags: magento, if-statement, php

I'm looking to define a specific attribute list by looking at the product id.

Currently I have the below, but I know it needs more work, especially as it's conflicting with the php within the enclosed divs.

Overall, I'd like it to say, if product id == 30 then display the following else display the norm.

Code is below.

```
<?php if($_product->getId() == "30")    
        {

        <div class="attribute_page">
        <p><span class="attribute_first">ISSN:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('issn')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Editor:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('editor')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Indexing Info:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('indexing_info')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Scope of Journal:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('scope_of_journal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>

        <p><span class="attribute_first">Purchasing Form:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('purchasing_form')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Download Product Flyer:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_flyer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a></p> 
        <p><span class="attribute_first">JSIS Homepage:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('jsis')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Recommend to Librarian:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('recommend_to_librarian')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p> 


        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
        </div>

        }
        else {

        <div class="attribute_page">
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Author:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('author')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Translation:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('translation')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Cover:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cover')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Google Books Preview:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_preview')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: why are you using both $product and $_product? Can you explain what errors you are getting or what is the exact problem?

Comment: woops..i've edited it now to $_product.

Currently with this code, it's breaking the product page. There isn't an error being brought up just no products either.

Answer (score 0):

Done it :)
After some research, I was just missing a few characters. The new code looks like this.

```
<?php if($_product->getId() == 30): ?>

        <div class="attribute_page">
        <p><span class="attribute_first">ISSN:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('issn')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Editor:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('editor')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Indexing Info:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('indexing_info')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Scope of Journal:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('scope_of_journal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Purchasing Form:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('purchasing_form')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Download Product Flyer:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_flyer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a></p> 
        <p><span class="attribute_first">JSIS Homepage:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('jsis')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Recommend to Librarian:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('recommend_to_librarian')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p> 
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
        </div>

        <?php else: ?>

        <div class="attribute_page">
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Author:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('author')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Translation:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('translation')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Cover:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cover')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
        <p><span class="attribute_first">Google Books Preview:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_preview')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code would also work if you had provide `<?php ?>` tag properly the code would go like this..

```
<?php if($_product->getId() == "30")    
    {  ?>

    <div class="attribute_page">
    <p><span class="attribute_first">ISSN:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('issn')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Editor:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('editor')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Indexing Info:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('indexing_info')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Scope of Journal:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('scope_of_journal')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>

    <p><span class="attribute_first">Purchasing Form:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('purchasing_form')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Download Product Flyer:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_flyer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download Here</a></p> 
    <p><span class="attribute_first">JSIS Homepage:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('jsis')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Recommend to Librarian:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('recommend_to_librarian')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p> 


    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
    </div>

    <?php }
    else { ?>

    <div class="attribute_page">
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Author:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('author')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Translation:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('translation')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Cover:</span> <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cover')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?></p>
    <p><span class="attribute_first">Google Books Preview:</span> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('google_preview')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click Here</a></p>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```